# Does $\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)\sim n \log n$ and $f$ monotonous increases means $f(n)\sim \log n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, asymptotics

> **Question**: Does $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n f(i)\sim n \log n$ and $f$ monotonous increases means $f(n)\sim \log n$, where $f$ is always positive?
>   $A(n)\sim B(n)$ means:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty } A(n)/B(n)=1
> $$

I haven't got any ideas yet(in fact, I don't even know where to begin my solution). Can anyone helps me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}f(i)$. Because $f$ is increasing we note that
$$nf(n)\le \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}f(i)=S_{2n}-S_n$$
So
$$\frac{f(n)}{\log n}\le 2\frac{\log n+\log2}{\log n}\cdot\frac{S_{2n}}{2n\log(2n)}-\frac{S_n}{n\log n}$$
It follows that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{\log n}\le 2-1=1.\tag{1}$$
Similarly,
$$nf(2n)\ge \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}f(i)=S_{2n}-S_n$$
So
$$\frac{f(2n)}{\log2n}\ge 2\frac{S_{2n}}{2n\log(2n)}-\frac{S_n}{n(\log n+\log2)}$$
It follows that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(2n)}{\log2n}\ge 2-1=1.\tag{2}$$
Combining (1) and (2) we see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(2n)}{\log2n}=1.\tag{3}$$
Now
$$\frac{\log2n}{\log(2n+1)}\cdot\frac{f(2n)}{\log2n}\le \frac{f(2n+1)}{\log(2n+1)}\le \frac{\log2n}{\log(2n+1)}\cdot\frac{f(2n+2)}{\log(2n+2)}$$
Taking limits we conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(2n+1)}{\log(2n+1)}=1.\tag{4}$$
From (3) and (4) the result follows.